# Can't install a OLE DB Provider for IBM DB2 ISeries on SQL Servers higher than 2008 version

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server

I've currently had a SQL Server 2008 server, which we now need to migrate to a newer edition.

We have a couple of linked servers which I have not set up personally which utilizes a provider called `IBMDASQL` in `SSMS`. It appears as if the previous collegue responsible for this set up has used the link [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978/) in order to set up these connections.

However, when I try to run the `Setup.exe` from the installation I get an immediate error telling me that I have a `Standard` edition which is not supported, and I can see from the documentation that only `SQL Server 2008` is supported.

How can I set up a OLE DB Provider for `IBMDASQL` (I need to get this working with a ISerie Connection)?

**EDIT**

I've tried to install `OleDB provider for DB2` from Microsoft, and it installed successfully. It was even included in my `Providers` list in Management Studio, but when I tried to set up a Connection using the same name for provider etc. as the previous Connection had, I got the error that `The OLD DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server abc reported an error. [....] cannot initialize data source object of OLE DB provider DB2OLEDB for linked server abc`. The same server used `IBMDASQL` earlier. I thought it was "included" in the DB2 OLE DB provider

On my previous installation I had the following settings:

Provider: IBM DB2 UDB for iSeries IBMDASQL OLE DB Provider
Product name: ISeries
Data Source: `[an IP number]`
Provider string:
Location:
Catalog: `foo`

the only difference I have in the new Connection is that

Provider: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for DB2

is used instead. Do I miss any steps?

Comment: IBMDASQL is the IBM OleDB provider for SQL Server.  Microsoft has an OleDB provider for DB2 also, see https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55183 which are you trying to install?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks for replying! I've tried to install `OleDB provider for DB2` from Microsoft, and it installed successfully. It was even included in my `Providers` list in Management Studio, but when I tried to set up a Connection using the same name for provider etc. as the previous Connection had, I got the error that `The OLD DB provider "DB2OLEDB" for linked server abc reported an error. [....] cannot initialize data source object of OLE DB provider DB2OLEDB for linked server abc`. The same server used `IBMDASQL` earlier. I thought it was "included" in the DB2 OLE DB provider

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Am I required to buy `Microsoft Access` in order to get this to work? I've seen some links implying that.

Comment: You shouldn't need anything related to Microsoft Access, which is part of Office.  The Microsoft driver is built by the Host Integration Server/ BizTalk team.  I don't know the setup/troubleshooting steps.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Have I misunderstood something in the bottom of my recent edit or something? If I dont miss anything, and the provider installed as expected and everything... I can only see that I either have a too new SQL server edition (2016) or that my configurations for the server is not the same.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the Microsoft provider, you'd need to use the Microsoft provider's name and not IBM's provider name.

The IBM provider is/was part of Client Access for Windows.  You don't mention what version you are trying to install, but the latest is v7r1 and it supports up to Windows 8.1.

IBM has replaced client Access for Windows with the new [Access Client Solution (ACS)](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/solutions.html).  ACS is split into two packages, an OS independent package and a OS dependent one.

The OLEDB driver is part of the ACS **Windows Application Package**.

Both the Client Access for Windows and the ACS Windows application package are licensed software and available only through IBM's [Entitled Software Support website (ESS)](https://www.ibm.com/servers/eserver/ess).  You'll need your IBM i folks to download it for you, or help you get access.